# Deserialize Json usinc C# , web api, asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, webapi

here is a sample of my JSON data, obtained from [this website](https://nbg.gov.ge/gw/api/ct/monetarypolicy/currencies/ka/json)

```json
[
  {
    "date": "2021-11-03T00:00:00.000Z",
    "currencies": [
      {
        "code": "AED",
        "quantity": 10,
        "rateFormated": "8.6246",
        "diffFormated": "0.0032",
        "rate": 8.6246,
        "name": "არაბეთის გაერთიანებული საამიროების დირჰამი",
        "diff": -0.0032,
        "date": "2021-11-02T17:44:59.825Z",
        "validFromDate": "2021-11-03T00:00:00.000Z"
      },
      {
        "code": "AMD",
        "quantity": 1000,
        "rateFormated": "6.6368",
        "diffFormated": "0.0036",
        "rate": 6.6368,
        "name": "სომხური დრამი",
        "diff": 0.0036,
        "date": "2021-11-02T17:44:59.825Z",
        "validFromDate": "2021-11-03T00:00:00.000Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

and My Classes -

```
public class CurrencyDTO
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string rateFormated { get; set; }
    public string diffFormated { get; set; }
    public double rate { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double diff { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public DateTime validFromDate { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public List<CurrencyDTO> currencies { get; set; }
}
```

when im trying to deserialize it for my site, model is showing but not data (see the pic)

[image: site-pic]

**Index Method**

```
                var webClient = new WebClient();
                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(BaseURL).Result;
                List<CurrencyDTO> ct = new List<CurrencyDTO>();
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    String rawJSON = webClient.DownloadString("https://nbg.gov.ge/gw/api/ct/monetarypolicy/currencies/ka/json");
                    ct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CurrencyDTO>>(rawJSON);
                }
                return View(ct);
```

**problem is my classes or the way im trying to deserialize it?**

Comment: When you debug the code do you see any data in `ct` variable? Can you share the view code also?

Comment: ct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(rawJSON);

Comment: im trying to add the debug points but nothing is happening

Comment: that gives me an error

Comment: Check the first lines of the JSON, it is not an array, but a class that has a date in a property named `date` and an array in a property named `currencies`. So you shuld use the class `Root` that has those properties in the deserialization.

Comment: If you're getting errors, share those with us.

Comment: Just use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(rawJSON)` instead of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CurrencyDTO>>(rawJSON)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, hope you will get the data:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(BaseURL).Result;
List<CurrencyDTO> ct = new List<CurrencyDTO>();
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    String rawJSON = webClient.DownloadString("https://nbg.gov.ge/gw/api/ct/monetarypolicy/currencies/ka/json");
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(rawJSON);
    ct = data.SelectMany(c => c.currencies).ToList();
}
return View(ct);
```

[image]

Comment: there is an error for data.currencies

Comment: Your `DeserializeObject<List<Root>>` should be `DeserializeObject<Root>`

Comment: @namizo Check my comment on this question about how to fix this answer and the explanation on your question comments.

Comment: What do you mean "because in json object it it not a correct datetime format"? That is a perfectly fine date format. https://dotnetfiddle.net/9f9tSV

Comment: I have edited ct = data.SelectMany(c => c.currencies).ToList(); this line. check now.

Comment: no, still no data

Comment: @gunr2171 I was checked in the original json file and seems it was wrong. But in the questions json looks good, so I removed that line from my answer.